# State management of multiple buttons

Tags: reactjs

I'm relatively new to React and I'm trying to understand how to manage state across multiple components. The example I'm using is quite basic as I'm trying to understand this at a higher level, particularly in terms of best practice.

For the example I'm working on, I have the following I'm trying to build:

[image]

Button 1 and Button 2 are always visible. When Button 1 is active, I want the child '1' buttons to be visible and '2' to be hidden, and when Button 2 is active, I want '2' to be active and '1' to be hidden.

I'm having trouble coming up with a state solution for this, because not only do I need to control active states for Button 1/2, I also need to manage button states for all the children, to ensure only 1 can be active at a time.

My understanding is that the state will need to be managed on the parent component, and fed through to the child button components.

So at the moment I have something like this:

```
<Parent>
  <Button>Button 1</Button>
  <Button>Button 2</Button>
  <Button>1</Button>
  <Button>1</Button>
  <Button>2</Button>
  <Button>2</Button>
<Parent>
```

I'm quite new to React and my initial thinking is that I'll have to implement a hook ie. `useState`. Would it be possible to use an array of values to hold the states of each of the buttons? I can then pass the state into each button as a prop to manage it's behaviour.

Something like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ button1Active: false, button2Active: true, button1Child1Active: false, button1Child2Active: false, button2Child1Active: true, button2ChildActive: false });
```

Then I could use setState to manipulate these values? However something tells me this isn't the 'correct' way of implementing this behaviour.

I'm just wondering if anyone could advise me on the ideal solution to managing the state of these components.

Thanks

Comment: Use one state for each button, otherwise the change of one button will trigger the re-render of all buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach for this solution would be this

```
const [activeGroup, setActiveGroup] = useState(1);
```

Your idea of using useState is on point but you are making it complex, activeGroup will be toggled to either '1' or '2' as needed

```
const toggleActiveGroup = () => {
   setActiveGroup(activeGroup === 1 ? 2 : 1);
};
```

and then we just need to conditionally render like this,

```js
<>
      <Button onClick={toggleActiveGroup}>Button 1</Button>
      <Button onClick={toggleActiveGroup}>Button 2</Button>
      {activeGroup === 1 && (
        <>
          <Button>1</Button>
          <Button>1</Button>
        </>
      )}
      {activeGroup === 2 && (
        <>
          <Button>2</Button>
          <Button>2</Button>
        </>
      )}
</>
```

Hope this helps, do ask question if u need more clarity

Comment: Thanks Salim, that does indeed handle the visibility of the buttons. My only dilemma now is how to manage the states of the buttons in each group. I only want one button active at a time, so surely that can't be handled within a single button's state as it needs to know about the state of the others?

Comment: @sterix24 don't put everything under one state, you don't want react to rerender all button if one button state is changing, have state for each button if you need it

Comment: I understand. But the issue is that for any button group, I only want one button active at a time. So I have to track /all/ button states in order to deactivate the ones that aren't selected?

Comment: so inside your example you said that you have two button groups 1 and 2 and when 1 is clicked you want only those 1 groups child to be active only and not 2 right? But you also want the child to be active conditionally like 1 child only?

Comment: Okay the way I am understanding is this for example you have 10 buttons inside group 1 and you want for eg a green background on one of its child indicating its active and the other child buttons are inactive. Here the better soulution would be this use a loop to generate the 10 buttons pass the index as key to uniquely identify them
and maintain a state (which defaults to zeroth id child button) and just use your states to conditionally add class of active or not

Comment: Yes that actually sounds like a great idea. I'll give it a shot - thanks for your help!